What are valid properties for AzureAD appsettings configuration with MSAL.NET
MSAL.NET is a library for .Net application to leverage EntraID as a Identity Provider.  There is a myriad of example apps provided by mslearn that include configuring the app with appsettings.json, in a configuration property named AzureAD that looks something like this:
AzureAD: {
  Instance: "",
  TenantId: "",
  Audiences: [],
  ClientId: ""
}

QUESTIONS:

is there any documentation on this AzureAD schema, what are the valid properties for difference scenarios?

I am working on a project that has a configuration property Audiences which I have not found in any the example applications.  Is there documentation defining Audiences as a valid property where I could understand why it is an array and why would an API list multiple Audiences?


I've search for MSAL.NET AzureAD appsettings schema and Micrososft.Identity AzureAD appsettings schema and similar search terms.  I was expecting to find the MSAL.NET appsettings configuration documented.

I have the same issue right now and found this one year old thread: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/2108
Not really too helpful sadly.
